# error C2248: cannot access private member declared in class

Tags: c++

I´m getting this error in a c++ application:

```
error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' :
              cannot access private member declared in class '
```

I have seen similar questions in stackoverflow, but I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code. Can someone help me?

```
    //header file
class batchformat {
    public:
        batchformat();
        ~batchformat();
        std::vector<long> cases;        
        void readBatchformat();
    private:
        string readLinee(ifstream batchFile);
        void clear();
};


    //cpp file
void batchformat::readBatchformat() 
{
    ifstream batchFile; 
    //CODE HERE
    line = batchformat::readLinee(batchFile);

}


string batchformat::readLinee(ifstream batchFile)
{
    string thisLine;
    //CODE HERE
    return thisLine;
}
```

Comment: Which line has the error?

Comment: @Mark: The error has no specific line. From the answers below, I already solved it by passing the parameter by ref.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is:

```
string readLinee(ifstream batchFile);
```

This tries to pass a copy of the stream by value; but streams are not copyable. You want to pass by reference instead:

```
string readLinee(ifstream & batchFile);
//                        ^
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string batchformat::readLinee(ifstream batchFile)
```

is trying to copy the ifstream
Take it by ref instead

```
string batchformat::readLinee(ifstream& batchFile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you can not pass the ifstream by value :

```
string readLinee(ifstream batchFile);
```

Pass it by ref instead :

```
string readLinee(ifstream& batchFile);
```

And I would suggest you to change a lign in the `readBatchformat` method :

```
void batchformat::readBatchformat() 
{
    ifstream batchFile; 
    //CODE HERE
    line = this->readLinee(batchFile);
    //      ^^^^^^
}
```

I think it is more readable.

Comment: `this->readLinee` is exactly equivalent to the OP's `batchformat::readLinee` (as is just `readLinee` without any qualification). Why do you think this change will help?

Comment: I think it is more understandable like that. With his code, we may think he is calling a static method (I think). But Iwas editing my post to point another mistake.

Comment: @doctorlove Of course not ! I was just saying that calling `line = batchformat::readLinee(batchFile);` seems like calling a static method, I think `line = readLinee(batchFile);` is more readable...